# Syntax Error while creating a Foreign Key Constraint

Tags: mariadb

Below is the code for creating Foreign Key constraint using MariaDB 10.5.13

```
create table a 
(

    id int primary key,
    name enum ("rajiv","harish","girish")
);

create table b
(
    id int primary key,
    givenName char(100),
    constraint gName
    foreign key(givenName) 
    references a (name)
    on delete cascade
    on update cascade
)




  Error Message:  SQL Error [1005] [HY000]: (conn=7) Can't create table `srkbs`.`b` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")
```

I want to use constraint keyword to name the foreign key.

Please help. Thanks!

Comment: Do you really need two tables in your case? You could just use `name` enumeration column in the `b` table. Actually enumeration substitutes the need for second table, because you have name strings (`rajiv`, `harish` etc.) already stored in `name` column metadata, you don't need to store them in a separate table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems:

1. The both columns don't have the same data type. The foreign key column and the referencing column must have same type and length.
2. The column which you try to use is no primary key, so you can't use it in a foreign key.

When those two issues are fixed, the foreign key will successfully be created, see the example here: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=ca5a0378d1a1c17f3916920c3d4e9a72)